# How can I get WebStorm to recognize Jasmine methods?

Tags: jasmine, webstorm

I have a [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) project that contains some [Jasmine](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/) specifications. The specifications are in a spec/ subdirectory and have the .spec.coffee extension, as required by [jasmine-node](https://github.com/mhevery/jasmine-node).

When I open one of my spec files in the [WebStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) IDE, all the calls to `beforeEach` and `describe` and `it` are shown with blue squiggly underlines with the tooltip: "Unresolved function or method it()". So even though I'm using the [3.0 EAP](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/WI/Web+IDE+EAP) and it's supposed to [have some amount of Jasmine support](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2011/10/javascript-unit-testing-support/), it's not automatically picking up on the fact that this is a Jasmine spec file.

I tried going into File > Settings > JavaScript Libraries, and adding Jasmine as a library (specifying the path to jasmine-2.0.0.rc1.js), and then going to the Usage Scope sub-page and checking "Jasmine" in the drop-down list next to "Project", but that had no effect -- the Jasmine methods still show up as unresolved.

How can I tell WebStorm that all files in a spec subdirectory, and/or all files with a .spec.coffee extension, are Jasmine tests, and have it recognize the Jasmine APIs those tests are using?

Comment: I have the same problem in 3.0 EAP. This is reason why I'm working in 2.1.5.

Comment: You should submit this as an issue at http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/WI so that developers can address such cases in the future versions.

Comment: @Microfed, so you're saying that 2.1.5 does automatically recognize Jasmine tests? Is this a bug that's already been written up?

Answer (score 241):

You can use predefined JS library stubs in Webstorm/PHPStorm/Idea

- Open **File > Settings...**
- Select **Languages & Frameworks** > **JavaScript > Libraries**
- Click on **Download...**

[image: JavaScript Library settings]

- Swich to **TypeScript community stubs**
- Find **karma-jasmine** (originally under the name **jasmine**) (If this does not work, try **jasmine** instead)
- Click on **Download and Install**

[image]

I am using this setup with Jasmine 2.0

Comment: I'm new to webstorm. What added functionality are you getting by doing this?

Comment: I think the only purpose is the autocomplete help (so the IDE do not need to process the library code and guess how the interface is defined).

That is basically said here: http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/javascript-libraries.html

Comment: and what about mocha?

Comment: I have no experience with mocha, but the library definition is available the same way as for jasmine

Comment: its called karma-jasmine, they changed it just to help us find it

Comment: Does not work for me. "describe", "beforeEach", "it" still appear with gray underline.

Comment: If you're not using karma, you can just pick the 'jasmine' library for download.  That's what worked for me after trying karma-jasmine

Comment: If you can't find it in the list, you already have it installed - enable it.  If this does not get rid of the squiggles after exiting Settings, the remove and redownload karma-jasmine.

Comment: Installing just Jasmine also enables Webstorm to also recognise Jasmine methods

Comment: This worked for me in PhpStorm using mocha and expect.js

Comment: Even though I'm using karma, I had to download just _jasmine_ to make it work. _karma-jasmine_ didn't work.

Comment: Using 'jasmine' library here works with TypeScript and Angular2 but causes a different error on the same Jasmine methods (regarding a missing files entry in tsconfig.json) - Adding the files entry fixed this BUT caused my TS files to stop auto compiling - the final much simpler solution is found in my answer below.

Comment: Last step - restart IDE

Comment: I followed @oujesky solution but I was forced to downgrade @types/jasmine to 2.5.41 to make it work. I use NodeJS 10.15.0 and TypeScript 2.5.3. 

[source](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/14569#issuecomment-279306281)

Answer (score 30):

On a mac with webstorm 2016.1.1 i did the following :

1. Open Preferences (webstorm->preference or [command + ,] )
2. Go to libraries and frameworks -> javascript -> libraries
3. download
4. select 'jasmine - DefinitelyTyped' from the list

[image: Jasmine support added to webstorm]

Comment: It worked for me on mac, but I needed to close and restart WebStorm.

Comment: I have downloaded the `jasmine` library using IntelliJ 2016.3 on a Windows machine and it worked, even *without* restarting.

Comment: I also had to change the "Type" from Global to Project. Double click the library name after installing it, then change the "Visibility" setting

Answer (score 6):

Note, if you are using a Code Quality Tool such as JSHint with WebStorm, adding the global jasmin/karma-jasmine library did not get rid of the JSHint errors.

You need to access the JSHint settings via WebStorm's menu system (Lang & Frameworks>JavaScript>Code Quality Tools>JSHint) and click the checkbox to enable it know which environment it is running in.

[image: JSHint setting]

Comment: Jasmine is missing from my environments. How did that appear in yours?

Comment: @AseemBansal what version of jshint are you using?

Comment: I am using version 2.5.10

Answer (score 4):

Using **TypeScript** (and Angular2) you just need to enable the TypeScript compiler in the WebStorm Settings ...

Settings > Languages & Settings > TypeScript ...

Under the Compiler heading tick ...

Enable TypeScript Compiler ...

(I also clicked the use tsconfig.json radio)

Jasmine methods will now be recognised

Comment: The issue with this solution is that I don't want `WebStorm` compiling my `TypeScript` since I am using `Webpack`.

Comment: Interestingly, if I make a `new project` as an `Angular CLI` project then it recognizes them. I am not sure what is different.

Comment: I use gulp to transpile my TypeScript, if you setup your tsconfig.json correctly then TypeScript will NOT generate output files, it will just validate them in the IDE.

Comment: Worked for me. Don't forget to tick the tsconfig.json

Comment: This almost worked without errors for me. However, when I do this I get this error output from the Typescript compiler tab in WebStorm:

Error:Error: Parse tsconfig error [{"messageText":"Unknown compiler option 'baseUrl'.","category":1,"code":5023},{"messageText":"Unknown compiler option 'lib'.","category":1,"code":5023},{"messageText":"Unknown compiler option 'typeRoots'.","category":1,"code":5023}]

Comment: I got the same complaint as you with the first answer: `corrisponding file not included in tsconfig.js`,  but i already did what you suggested I do

Answer (score 4):

This could also be caused by a missing dependency (if you're developing in TypeScript).

Make sure you've installed `@types/jasmine`

```
npm install --save-dev @types/jasmine
```

Answer (score 2):

If you encounter this issue after having generated a project using the `Angular CLI` then go to `File -> Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> JavaScript -> Libraries` and check `{your-project-name}/node_modules`.

Answer (score 0):

To find the answer to this, I ran [DiffMerge](https://sourcegear.com/diffmerge/downloads.php) on my project root and a new Angular CLI project created in Webstorm that properly detected jasmine types.

What I found is that the `tsconfig.json` and `tsconfig.spec.json` files *from my project* defined `typeRoots` and `types`, whereas the other project did not.

[image]

The behavior of the [`typeRoots`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#typeRoots) option is:

> If typeRoots is specified, only packages under typeRoots will be included.

`Types` behaves a similar way.

Typescript documentation goes on to say:

> By default all visible ”@types” packages are included in your compilation. Packages in node_modules/@types of any enclosing folder are considered visible.

So, for my project, this behavior is good enough for me. Deleting `typeRoots` and `types` from both my `tsconfig.json` and `tsconfig.spec.json` files solved this *immediately*.

Yes, jasmine was declared under `types` in `tsconfig.spec.json`. Yes, it was set to extend `tsconfig.json`.

In this case, it didn't matter. One day it just stopped working. Possibly due to a Typescript upgrade, but I can't say for certain. If anyone knows why, please leave a comment below, I'm curious.