# WebStorm: Specs are showing unknown functions

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, gulp, webstorm, yeoman-generator

First time to use Angular.js - started a few days ago. I got set up using the gulp angular yeoman generator.

In WebStorm, my specs are showing unknown symbols: `it`, `describe` are unknown, as well as assertions like `toEqual`

However, tests run ok using gulp from the cmd-line.

[image]

How can I tell tell WebStorm where to find these symbols?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WebStorm should have picked up all you dependencies from your bower file automatically. Did yeoman generate `bower.json` file for you?

In any case, you can add additional library support in WebStorm ([docs](http://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.1/javascript-libraries.html?origin=old_help)). Go to:

- **Windows & Linux:** *File | Settings | Languages and Frameworks | JavaScript | Libraries*
- **OSX**: *WebStorm | Preferences | Languages and
  Frameworks | JavaScript | Libraries*

and add `jasmine` or `karma-jasmine` there. Also, see [this SO answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22660525/52317).

Comment: I can see Jasmine in node modules, but not in bower_components. Perhaps the gulp file is using the one from node modules directory. This is all very new to me. Thank you.